# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InstrumentosImport' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola**

Estoy tratando de importar datos a mi base de datos mySQL desde un archivo de excel, me encuentro usando la libreia de laravel Excel version 3.1 pero me encuentro con ese problema en el codigo de mi controlador (import) adjunto el codigo de dicho controlador:

```
namespace App\Imports;

 use App\tbl_instrumentos;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

    class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
    {

public function model(array $row)
{
    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[1],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[2],

    ]);
  }
}
```

Adjunto el codigo de mi controlador principal:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\tbl_calibracion;
use DB;
use Excel;

class TestController extends Controller
{

public function importExportView()
{
   return view('importar');
}


public function exportExcel($type) 
{
    return Excel::download(new InstrumentosExport, 'instrumentos.'.$type);
}

/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function importExcel(Request $request) 
{
    Excel::import(new InstrumentosImport,$request->import_file);

    return back();
}

}
```

**GRACIAS**

Comment: te falta importar esa clase en tu controlador `use App\Imports\InstrumentosImport;`

Answer (score 1):

Como dice el error, no has agregado la dependencia de tu clase `InstrumentosImport` a tu controllador.

```
use App\Imports\InstrumentosImport;
```